# Pv Cells operating on ambient light

Tags: led

I am needing to understand is PV cells work on light in general or only sunlight?
I have a project that needs to use pv cells inside to harness ambient light and focussed/captured  LED source light to regenerate battery cells in a display... is this possible ?
I need to generate enough battery energy to power 56W of LED's for 12 hrs and cyclically regenerate with some grid recharge as necessary but am trying to understand the lack of efficiency of a system like this ?

Comment: You probably understand what you want. But you wrote too little for me, I think. Are you imagining trying to _recover_ energy from your LED lights using PV?

Comment: There is a huge difference between full sunlight outdoors and ambient light indoors at night, a factor of 1000 or more. If a PV cell delivers 100 W in full sunlight, you may get less than 0.1 W indoors. Powering 56 W for 12 hours will require a fairly large battery and also a very large PV cell to load the battery during the day. But if there is not enough light energy inside the room, even a huge PC cell as large as the ceiling of the room will not help.

Answer (score 3):

PV cells do work in all levels of light (ambient light is enough to make my calculator work) BUT there are so many orders of magnitude difference in light intensity between indoors and outdoors that indoor operation gives a pathetic power harvest. You would be very hard pressed to recover one watt indoors with panels covering every wall, let alone the 10s of watts you would need for your LED requirement.

The current produced is more or less proportional to the light input. At a low enough light, the output voltage drops off as well and the conversion efficiency falls.

Comment: As an example, a solar powered toy motor spins like crazy in weak sunlight.  To get the same effect with indoor lighting requires placing a 20W halogen desklamp  right in front of the solar cell.